# Best implementation to remove duplicates JAVA array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Found this solution to make this method:

```
int[] withoutDuplicates(int[] a){
int n = a.length;
   if (n < 2) {
        return a; 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) { 
         for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
               if (a[j] == a[i]) {
                 --n;
                 System.arraycopy(a, j+1, a, j, n-j);
                --j; 
             }//end if
        } //end for
     }//end for

     int[] aa = new int[n]; 
     System.arraycopy(a, 0, aa, 0, n); 
     return aa;

}//end method
```

I do not understand why it is using an array of length n. Shouldn't it be of size n minus the number of duplicates erased?
Is this the most optimal way of implementing the method? or is there any java resource I could use?

Comment: It _is_ n minus the number of duplicates. `--n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am, by nature, lazy.  I would do this:

-- EDIT --

```
private int[] withoutDuplicates(int[] a){
    Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : a) {
        set.add(x);
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[set.size()];
    int ii = 0;
    for (Integer x : set) {
        newArray[ii++] = x;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: It changes the order of it. That could be a unwished side effect of a duplicate erase method i think ;)

Comment: `set.toArray(new int[]{})` doesn't compile ... If the method signature used Integer[] it would.

Comment: I assumed it would perform the auto-unboxing... I'll update shortly.

Comment: Thanks, good observation

Comment: Here's a fixed, compilable implementation.  It has the added benefit of preserving the order.  Thanks @pL4Gu33 for the catch.

Comment: That code looks really good. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm for removing duplicates and maintaining the relative order.
Time: O(n)
Space: O(n)

```
public static void dupCheck(int [] a){
        int j=0;
        HashMap<Integer,Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
        int [] b = new int [a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(!map.containsKey(a[i])){
                map.put(a[i],true);
                b[j++]=a[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
            System.out.print(b[i]+" ");
    }
```